# preg_replace double quotation mark not following a comma

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to find the correct Regex pattern to replace double quotation mark when it's not after comma `,`

In the below string only remove one double quotation mark when it comes after some characters which are not delimiter/comma

```
"ahys"", "hshs","", "277-""
```

The above string changes to this after `preg_replace`

```
"ahys", "hshs","", "277-"
```

I am using this pattern but it's not working - it doesn't only replace quotation marks but also one character from left side

```
preg_replace('/([^"",])["]["]/', '"', '"ahys"", "hshs","", "277-""');
```

Results:

> "ahy", "hshs","", "277"

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my pattern here?

Comment: `[^"",]` means "Not quote and not comma". having two `"` in there is pointless, since it's a character class. `[aa]` and `[a]` will execute identically. and single character char-classes are similarly useless. `"` and `["]` also execute identically.

Comment: just replace "" with "

Comment: @MarcB got it thanks but my problem still remains

Comment: Is it possible to have more than two consecutive double quotes? In this case what do you want to do? Other question, what happens if an item *(i.e. a substring enclosed between double quotes)* ends with a comma and is closed with two double quote?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte There wouldn't be two consecutive double quotes - closed with two double quotes like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
(?<!^|,\s|,)"(?!,|$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/cE2yD0/1

It uses lookarounds to find `"`s that meet the following criteria:

- Not at the start or end of a string
- Not preceded or succeeded by a `,` (with optional space before the `"`)

Answer (score 1):

If you dont' want to use regex lookarounds then you can use a regex like this:

```
("[\w-]+?")"
```

With a substitution string:

```
$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/lK3sC8/1)**

Code

```
$re = '/("[\w-]+?")"/'; 
$str = "\"ahys\"\", \"hshs\",\"\", \"277-\"\"\n"; 
$subst = "$1"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: This works nicely as long as there is only a single enclosed " and it is adjacent to the closing ".  But that might meet the OP's requirements.

Comment: @dustmouse yes, posted the answer additionally to yours since may be the case.

Comment: definitely.  It's a nice lookaround-free solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use str_replace which is faster

```
<?php

    $str = 'test one -> " <- removed, not -> ", <- removed, not -> ," <- removed'

    echo str_replace( array( '",', ',"', '"', '%@@%,', ',%@@%' ), array( '%@@%,', ',%@@%', '', '",', ',"'), $str );

    // prints test one ->  <- removed, not -> ", <- removed, not -> ," <- removed

?>
```